# Trouble with Angular 2 http.get method

Tags: angular, apache, http

Salutations. I'm trying to learn Angular 2 by rebuilding the front end of a project I did previously while using the same back end code. The original project used jQuery on the front end and PHP in the back. I'm at the point where I want to start hooking my the front end to the back but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently I have my original back end code running on apache2 on localhost and test Angular app is running on localhost:4200. The back end file I'm trying to access is at ajax.php (path is 'localhost/pokemon/ajax.php') and I have a line in that file to log an error whenever that file is referenced.

When I do http.get from my Angular 2 service and log the result on my component, I get 
    `[object Object]`
And the ajax.php doesn't log the message so it seemingly hasn't been called.

Here's my code. I The functions in question are near the bottom of each file.

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    //return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    return null;
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }

  //calls http.get
  testFunc() {
    console.log("Test func is being called in the service");
    return of(this.http.get('localhost/pokemon/ajax.php?method=getTypes'));
  }
}
```

And the component I'm trying to test with

heroes.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Init is being called");
    //this.getHeroes();
    this.testFunc();
  }

  //calls the test function
  testFunc(): void {
    console.log("Test function is being called");
    this.heroService.testFunc()
      .subscribe(
        data => console.log("Got this: " + data),
        err => console.log("Error " + err),
        () => console.log("Done!")
      );
  }
}
```

I also tried to get the data from a live server with the same app but the result was the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the correctness of the `url` but the reason you are getting `[object]` in console is because of the logging syntax. Use this syntax instead `console.log("Got this", data);`, do the same for error callback log.

Comment: Is the return not incorrect? The http.get is already returning a observable if I'm correct. Now you are returning a Observable<Observable<T>>. 

And as the observable of http.get is not subscribed it will never make the call.

Comment: use console.log(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: You don't need `of(this.http.get())`, as `this.http.get()` already returns an observable. You are wrapping one observable in another! You can just `return this.http.get('...')`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I changed the way I was logging errors and stopped returning an observable of an observable and it seems to have cleared things up. Now I'm getting another (cryptic) error but I think I'll open up a new question for that.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

this code may be help you

```
this.heroService.testFunc().subscribe(
            (data => {
                if (data["_body"] && data["_body"] != "") {
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(data["_body"]));

                };
            }),
            error => this.toastr.error('Something went wrong !!', 'Oops!', {showCloseButton: true})
        );
```

and in your service

```
 testFunc() {
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:4200(the port on which your php code running)/pokemon/ajax.php', user).map(() => "your method or "" ");
    }
```

if you need any help comment

Answer (score 0):

try like this. it will work

```
getusers() {
    const headers = new Headers(
             {
                 accept: 'application/json/'
             });
         const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     return this.http.get(this.url, options).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

and in your calling function 
 get() {

```
  this.service.getusers().subscribe(a => {
    this.a = a;
    // console.log(a.length);
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got a few comments which were all quite helpful -- I was returning of(http.get(..)) which messed things up and I wasn't logging the errors I was receiving to the console properly.

It's still not working as I expected but it's enough to move on so I'll open up a new question since the current issue is mostly solved.
Thanks all!